# How to maintain two domains in the same installation having different $base_url

Tags: ajax, multi-sites

I have published a new domain for my drupal installation. It has a fixed $base_url configured in settings.php. For example: https://www.olddomain.com.ar . It throws an ajax exception when I use a textfield with an autocomplete_path under the new domain https://new.domain.com.ar

The error is:
"An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally."

can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you please explain your setup a bit more detailed? Normally serving similar content from two different domains is considered duplicate content as in SEO suicide.

Comment: And have you already tried to remove the base URL from your settings.php, like outcommenting the line for example?

Comment: A possible alternative would be to use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] in your settings.php to determine which $base_url to use.

Comment: I have a different robots.txt file for each domain. Removing the base_url cause 404 in some CSS resource. Finally, I'm configuring multisite folowing this step and work successfully. [drupal.org/docs/] : https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/multisite-drupal/configuring-a-basic-multi-site-development-environment-in-linux